# Get the value of a form element returned from an ajax callback function

Tags: 7, ajax, forms

I have a select element and submit button in my form :

```
$form = array();

$form['myid_template'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Select Template'),    
    '#suffix' => '<div id="myid_dynamic_input_information"></div>',
); 

$form['myid_template']['template_options'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',        
    '#options' => array(
         1 => t("Student"),
         2 => t("Employee"),         
     ),
     '#default_value' => 1,
     '#title' => t('Select'),                  
     '#ajax' => array(
         'callback' => 'myid_select_template',
         'wrapper' => 'myid_dynamic_input_information',
     ),                             
); 

 $form['submit'] = array(
     '#type' => 'submit',
     '#value' => 'Save',         
     '#ajax' => array(
         'event' => 'click',
         'callback' => 'myid_user_page_form_ajax_submit',                     
     ),     
 );
```

My select form element calls an ajax function `myid_select_template` that adds a field and updates the form.

```
function myid_select_template($form, $form_state){
      $form = array();
      $form['form']= array(
          '#type' => 'fieldset',       
          '#title' => t("Employee's Information"),                
      );     

      $form['form']['template2_field1'] = array(
          '#title' => t('GSIS No.'),
          '#type' => 'textfield',    
          '#description' => "Government Service Insurance System number.",   
          '#attributes' => array(
              'id' => $template . '_field1' ,
          ),
      );
      return $form;
}
```

My problem is, after `myid_select_template` is called, whenever I click the submit button , I cant access `$form['form']['template2_field1']` from `myid_user_page_form_ajax_submit` callback function.

```
function myid_user_page_form_ajax_submit($form, &$form_state) { 
    dsm($form);
    dsm($form_state);
}
```

I did try to display my `$form` and `$form_state` variables but I cant find the value of `$form['form']['template2_field1']` in it. What should I do? Does it have connection in rebuilding the form? Do I have to rebuild the form to update the `$form_state`variable? If yes, how?

Comment: Inspect the element in your browser whether there is name attribute for that field? I hope it wont be there...

Comment: @VinodkumarSaravana --> Thanks, I wasted almost 1 day, trying to figure it out. Thank you so much. Please put your answer on the answer section and I will mark it as the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too not sure why the name attribute is not adding to the field. but you can bring by explicitly defining the name in the field.

```
 $form['form']['template2_field1'] = array(
      '#title' => t('GSIS No.'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#name' => 'template2_field1',    
      '#description' => "Government Service Insurance System number.",   
      '#attributes' => array(
          'id' => $template . '_field1' ,
      ),
  );
```